# Why do I get an acces violation in the datamodule when nothing is happening?

Tags: delphi

I have made a data module and a button. When I send info to the data module it gives an access violation when the program is done even when nothing needs to be done. What is going wrong? I use Delphi XE on w8.1.

```
procedure TForm1.btnCalcClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ACake: TCake;
begin
  ACake.Diameter:= StrToFloat(edtDiam.Text);
  modMain.Calc(ACake);
end;
```

Here is the data module unit:

```
interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, classdef;

type
  TmodMain = class(TDataModule)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Calc(ACake: TCake);
  end;

var
  modMain: TmodMain;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'System.Classes.TPersistent'}

{$R *.dfm}

{ TmodMain }

procedure TmodMain.Calc(ACake: TCake);
begin

end;

constructor TmodMain.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

end;

destructor TmodMain.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;

end.
```

To clarify my class definitions unit I will post it here.

Here is my classdef unit:

```
unit classdef;

interface


type
  TCake = class
  private
    FDiameter: Double;
  public
    property Diameter: Double read FDiameter write FDiameter;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

Comment: did you create TModMain and TCake?

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the `inherited` in TmodMain.Destroy.  When the debugger stops there, evaluate `Self`.  Is it Nil or some other value?  And if TCake is a class, you need to call Create on it before trying to use (and Free afterwards to avoid a memory leak).

Comment: @MartynA the debugger does not stop there.

Comment: @whosrdaddy no I did not. I'll edit my post to show you my class. Should I insert a create and destroy function in the class?

Comment: Well, I'm baffled why you think your btnCalcClick could possibly do anything useful.  I think you might do better to start again and re-think your code from scratch.

Comment: @MartynA The button was not suppose to do anything for now. It will later on calculate something. For now I want to setup the hierarchy. Could you help me explain it? If I understand correctly Tmodmain and TCake were not created so I need to create it somewhere and free it to clean up and prevent memory leak errors.

Comment: Well, including code that's not supposed to do anything (and never will, as written), just wastes the time of readers who you are asking for help.  Anyway, start by checking that your datamodule is on the project's autocreate list and that it's created before Form1.  Then, decide what your Cake's lifetime should be and create&free it in the appropriate places.  Maybe make it a field of TmodMain, in which case the places are the OnCreate and OnDestroy events of TmodMain.

Comment: General advice: `var modMain: TmodMain;` is a global variable. Try to get rid of those as much as possible. Create instances in code where you have to and store them in variables with a lower visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to create a class instance before you can use it.
In this example I assume that your datamodule has been autocreated by the IDE.

So your code:

```
procedure TForm1.btnCalcClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ACake: TCake;
begin
  ACake.Diameter:= StrToFloat(edtDiam.Text);
  modMain.Calc(ACake);
end;
```

becomes:

```
procedure TForm1.btnCalcClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ACake: TCake;
begin
  ACake := TCake.Create; 
  try
   ACake.Diameter:= StrToFloat(edtDiam.Text);
   modMain.Calc(ACake);
  finally
   ACake.Free;
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: Sorry, but unless modMain.Calc has some persistent side-effect, btnCalcClick is still pointless.

Comment: @MartynA: yes indeed,but that's not the point i'm trying to make :)

Comment: Sure, but I suspect it will be lost on the OP.

Comment: No it's not lost. The button is for now on purpose useless.